# Obtaining contours of the image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, image

I would like to obtain contours(outline) of the image (black and white thin curve version of the original image). Outline that would just look nice.

#### First attempt

I first try using `EdgeDetect` however result just doesn't look very good. The shape of the head and torso looks good, however lips and nose looks quite unnatural.

```
image = Import[
   "https://i.imgur.com/fFmetq6_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand"];
Thinning[EdgeDetect[image]]
```

[image]

#### Second attempt

I then thought that maybe I should try to detect contour instead first. However `ContourDetect` seems to loose a lot of detail even with different delta values.

```
EdgeDetect[ContourDetect[image, 0.5]]
```

[image]

Do you have any idea how could I obtain pretty looking outline of the image?

Comment: You can first take the row or column of the pixels that goes through the interesting region and apply the `MinMax` to corresponding set of color channels. Next, you should take the edge value in between the obtained Min and Max.

Answer (score 5):

Edgedetect gives a binary image. Faces really aren't binary. Perhaps GradientFilter is worth a look:

```
Manipulate[GradientFilter[image, {s, t}] // ImageAdjust, 
                                 {s, {1, 2, 3}}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Here I used the Manipulate to find "good" values of the parameters of the gradient.

[image]